# Compilation error calling Function with Table Parameter from Procedure

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, plsql

In a package, I have:

1. A Type of Table of Numbers
2. A Function that takes said Table of Numbers type as a parameter
3. A Procedure that needs to call said Function using Table of Numbers type

I know the Type works, I know the Function works.  But when I try to call the Function within the Procedure, I get the following Compilation errors:

> Error(262,16): PLS-00306: wrong number or types of arguments in call
>   to '[FUNCTION]' Error(262,16): PL/SQL: ORA-00904:
>   "[PACKAGE]"."[FUNCTION]": invalid identifier Error(264,41): PLS-00642:
>   local collection types not allowed in SQL statements

Package Header:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE [PACKAGE] AS 

    TYPE NUMBER_LIST IS TABLE OF NUMBER;

    FUNCTION [FUNCTION] (
        [LIST_PARAM]       NUMBER_LIST
      ) RETURN VARCHAR2;

    PROCEDURE [PROCEDURE] (
        RECORDS_AFFECTED    OUT NUMBER
      );

END [PACKAGE];
```

Problem Code:

```
  PROCEDURE [PROCEDURE](
      RECORDS_AFFECTED    OUT NUMBER
  )AS
      [ID_LIST]  NUMBER_LIST;
  BEGIN
      ...

      SELECT  [COLUMN]
      BULK COLLECT INTO    [ID_LIST]
      FROM    [TABLE]

      INSERT INTO [TABLE]( [COLUMN] )
      SELECT   [FUNCTION]( LIST_PARAM => [ID_LIST] )
      FROM    [OTHER TABLE];

      ...  
  END [PROCEDURE];
```

And the error revolves around this line:

```
SELECT   [FUNCTION]( LIST_PARAM => [ID_LIST] )
```

I have tried:

```
[ID_LIST]  NUMBER_LIST;
[ID_LIST]  [PACKAGE].NUMBER_LIST;

SELECT   [FUNCTION]( [ID_LIST] )
SELECT   [FUNCTION]( LIST_PARAM => [ID_LIST] )
SELECT   [PACKAGE].[FUNCTION]( [ID_LIST] )
SELECT   [PACKAGE].[FUNCTION]( LIST_PARAM => [ID_LIST] )
```

But I feel like the problem is in the way the [ID_LIST] is being passed.

Any thoughts on what I'm doing wrong passing this Type TABLE OF NUMBER parameter to the function?

Comment: What version of Oracle do you use, 11g, 12c ? In 11g you cannot use PL/SQL types (declared in the Pl/SQL package/procedure/function) in SQL statements, you have to use schema level types. In 12c this restriction was relaxed.

Comment: I am having this problem on 12c but the software needs to be backwards compatible with 11g, so thank you for pointing out this limitation as well

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem isn't the parameter list to the function per se, it's that you're trying to use the locally defined type NUMBER_LIST in an SQL statement (that's the PLS-00642 error).  The SQL engine knows nothing about this type.  You would have to create a database type for this to succeed e.g.:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE  TYPE NUMBER_LIST IS TABLE OF NUMBER;
```

or else something like this:

```
  PROCEDURE [PROCEDURE](
      RECORDS_AFFECTED    OUT NUMBER
  )AS
      [ID_LIST]  NUMBER_LIST;
      fnc_ret    VARCHAR2;
  BEGIN
      ...

      SELECT  [COLUMN]
      BULK COLLECT INTO    [ID_LIST]
      FROM    [TABLE]

      fnc_ret := [FUNCTION]( LIST_PARAM => [ID_LIST] );

      INSERT INTO [TABLE]( [COLUMN] )
      VALUES (fnc_ret);

      ...  
  END [PROCEDURE];
```

You'll likely need to modify this to suit your real code, but this is the idea.  You just can't use ID_LIST in an SQL statement without making it a database defined type, as the SQL engine can't see it.

PL/SQL is one "engine" within the RDBMS.  It has a statement processor, and when it encounters a SQL statement, it hands it off to the SQL "engine" for processing. I think you can see why that causes the problem.

Comment: your suggestion to use a database type was successful.
Is it possible I could skip the type altogether and just create the parameter as the TABLE OF DECIMAL to begin with?

Comment: I don't know of a way to do that.