# Oracle PL/SQL local collection type not allowed error

Tags: oracle, plsql

Regards! Is there a way of performing the logic presented in the code below on Oracle SQL? I get error PLS-00642: local collection types not allowed in SQL statements; for variable var1, and var2...

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE TEST IS
    CURSOR c1 IS SELECT * FROM Table1;
    TYPE num_arr_type IS TABLE OF NUMBER(5);
    i_rec Table1%ROWTYPE;
    var1 num_arr_type;
BEGIN
    var1:= SELECT num FROM Table3;
    OPEN c1;
      LOOP
        FETCH c1 INTO i_rec;
        EXIT WHEN c1%NOTFOUND;

          SELECT a.num                
            FROM Table2 a
           WHERE a.cod_agt = var1;

      END LOOP;    
    CLOSE c1;

END TEST;
```

In my code I would like to store a SELECT result into a variable, and use the variable in a WHERE clause of another select statement. Is that possible?

Comment: You have some issues here. It would be easier for people to help you if you could post some sample data, needed result and descibe the logic you want to implement.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Compilation error calling Function with Table Parameter from Procedure](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41023727/compilation-error-calling-function-with-table-parameter-from-procedure)

Comment: Your edit is even more confusing than the original post. What should this do? And what is the issue with this code? Does this give the error you posted?

Comment: Sorry, I re-edited my code. In my code I would like to store a SELECT result into a variable, and use the variable in a WHERE clause of another select statement. Is that possible?

Comment: Sounds line an `in (subquery)` construction in SQL.

Comment: if your select returns a single row, you can use `select num into var1 from table3`. If nothing is returned, you will get NO_DATA_FOUND exception. If more than 1 record is returned, you will get TO_MANY_ROWS exception.

Comment: What is it you're going to do with the results once you've fetched from your cursor and manually replicated database joins? Is the data going to be inserted somewhere? Used to update something? Summed and returned to the calling procedure? etc etc etc

Comment: Also, as things stand, your procedure doesn't make any sense - you're looping through X rows in one table and then effectively running another query X times with the exact same predicate. Presumably this is an example you've generated; if you could make it match your actual real-world problem more closely, you'd get a better set of answers.

Comment: Ok, so in real scenario I want to to #1: store a SELECT result into a variable ( `var1 NUMBER:= SELECT num FROM Table1`). Then, #2 I would like to `INSERT INTO Table x WHERE num IN var1`. That's basically the logic. I'm not stating the way I'm doing it is the correct approach... that's my original question, what is the best approach of performing this. So far @Aleksej approach is the one that makes more sense, but if there's a more effective method please let me know. Thanks!

Comment: If you need to copy data from a table to another, you do not need plsql at all, but you may simply need an `insert ... select ... from ...`. Please post an example, with some data, of what you need to do to get a good answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I would like to store a SELECT result into a variable, and use the
>   variable in a WHERE clause of another select statement. Is that
>   possible

I am not sure what you want to achieve but looking at you statements above I give an example below:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE TEST IS
    CURSOR c1 IS 
    SELECT * FROM Table1;

    TYPE num_arr_type IS TABLE OF NUMBER(5);

    var1  num_arr_type;

    i_rec Table1%ROWTYPE;
    v_num number;

BEGIN
     --- This is how you store value to a collection
    SELECT num
      bulk collect into  var1
    FROM Table3;

     --- Loop to get individual records from your collection
   For i in 1..var1.count
    loop    
       SELECT a.num  
         into  v_num             
            FROM Table2 a
           --This is how you pass the value stored in your collection one by one in loop.
           WHERE a.cod_agt = var1(i);   

       dbms_output.put_line(v_num);  
    end loop;             

END TEST;
```